# Admin toolbar doesn't appear

Tags: 7, toolbar

My admin toolbar doesn't showing up. `$page_top` in html.tpl.php doesn't have any value.

Why doesn't `$page_top` have any value? How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you check it's value? How do you do it?

Comment: In html.tpl.php, I erased all the code except print $page_top

Comment: Is it any problem with the database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it.

Stupid mistake by me. I'm new to Drupal. I tried to create user (admin) directly from the database. Yes, I can login, but the admin toolbar(menu) will not appear.

How to solve the problem?

- Just create user with the normal(correct) way - from the website.
- Don't create user directly from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS.

```
#admin-menu, #admin-menu .dropdown {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.logged-in #oa-navbar {
  top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: No. It will not work because there will be no element that have id #admin-menu.

print $page_top should print all the admin toolbar. But in my case, $page_top doesn't have any value.

$page_top="";

Comment: "regions[page_top] = Page top" ,check your .info file of theme this region is defined or not .

Comment: yes, the regions[page_top] is defined in my .info file.